# Authy/Twilio OTP in Django without custom user model

Tags: django, django-models, one-time-password, authy

I'm trying to learn how to use Authy/Twilio in a new Django app. I found this helpful demo application https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/account-security-quickstart-django which I was reading through to see how it all worked. I noticed in the [settings.py](https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/account-security-quickstart-django/blob/master/account_security/settings.py#L135) file they referenced a custom user model, which I found [here](https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/account-security-quickstart-django/blob/master/twofa/models.py). The custom model looks very basic and doesn't have much of the info stored in the regular user model.

My questions are:

1. Is it required to use this custom model or can you somehow add the
   required info into the existing/default user model?
2. How would this integrate with Django apps using something else (like
   ldap) as the backend instead of the django db user model?

Comment: I think you must focus on asking one question at a time. But for 1. additional fields like this should go in a custom user model.

Comment: You can't change the standard user model. It's a very good idea to start with your own user model. If you start a project with the standard user and need to change it after that, it's very difficult. Read this; https://wsvincent.com/django-custom-user-model-tutorial/

Comment: And there's a package for LDAP with django; https://django-auth-ldap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/